# Are Avahi and Bonjour compatible?

Tags: networking, macintosh, printer, avahi

I would like to set up a network printer on my Linux desktop (Parabola GNU/Linux, derivative of Arch) so that my wife can connect to it with her Macbook. I understand that Linux uses Avahi to share printers with a local network, but Apple Macs use Bonjour for printer sharing. They look like similar (zeroconf) technologies - to what extent are they compatible? Is there anything special I need to do, to allow a Mac to connect to a printer I share with Avahi (over wifi)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Avahi and Bonjour are both implementations of [Multicast DNS (mDNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) and [DNS Service Discovery (DNS-SD)](http://www.dns-sd.org/), which are standardized by the IETF and fully compatible. For printing specifically, [CUPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS), the print server used on both macOS and most Linux systems, uses the [Internet Printing Protocol (IPP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol) under the hood, which is published under a standard DNS-SD service type (`_ipp._tcp`) that macOS should have no trouble understanding.